# Difference between "ignorant" and "uninformed"

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between *ignorant* and *uninformed*? In ordinary usage, is one considered a put down and the other considered a statement of fact? If so, why? Am I ignorant or simply uninformed?

Comment: Not an answer as such, but I think it's worth mentioning that the word *ignorant* has a rather different meaning in Scotland and parts of the Caribbean, to that in the rest of the English-speaking world.

Comment: @Mark And that meaning is ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure of a precise definition, but it seems to be something like "arrogantly stupid", as opposed to merely uninformed.

Comment: In southern U.S. dialects, "_ignernt_" (ignorant) is used to mean either unintelligent or stupid, "Well that's just ignert!" "Ignorant" has a stronger derogatory connotation than "uninformed".

Comment: @MarkBannister. There's a similar usage in Ireland. Here, *ignorant* seems to mean "belligerent" as much as anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People often contrast "stupid" from "ignorant". "Stupid" means a lack of intelligence, an inability to comprehend information. "Ignorant" means a lack of information.

"Uninformed" means pretty much the same thing as "ignorant". It has a milder tone, but that's about the only difference.

Answer (score 7):

Ignorant means the person in question did not *bother* to "get informed". Being uninformed can have several causes, not necessarily that of not showing concern.

Comment: *Ignorant* implies a lack of sophistication and education. *Uninformed* doesn't necessarily mean you are uneducated; you just haven't received a particular piece of information yet.

Comment: That's can't be right, because children are ignorant, but it's not a question as to whether they are bothering or not.

Comment: @vy32 That's _exactly_ what it is.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I hate to disagree with @Milosz, but negativity attaches to both adjectives. Calling someone *uninformed* is simply a politer way of calling them *ignorant*.

If you're looking for a more neutral adjective, try *unaware*.

Comment: Can we get a definitive reference, rather than just some opinions?

Comment: @vy32 Although I understand your frustration, I'm afraid a definitive reference wouldn't be of much help, even if one was to be found. This question seems to be more about individuals' personal opinion rather than any conventions (or lack of those), as illustrated by the equal distribution of votes amongst seemingly contrasting answers.

Comment: As to @Robusto's answer, whilst it is common to say something along the lines of _"I was not wrong, I was uninformed"_ or _"A well-intentioned but uninformed advice"_, paraphrasing those sentences using _ignorant_ would result in a significant difference in connotation.

Comment: As with many such terms, a lot depends on how you say it. Like if you say, "No, wait, Sally, I think you are just uninformed about how to enter data into the new computer system," that would probably be understood as more explanation than criticism. But if you say, "I can't believe somebody could be as ignorant as you! Do you need help dressing yourself?!" that would probably be taken as an insult.

Comment: Disagree.  Context can attach negativity to practically any word, but no negativity at all conventionally attaches to *uninformed* as the word *in and of itself* is used by good writers, any more than negativity conventionally attaches to *forgotten* or *short.*  The word in this sense is not at all like *thankless* or *wicked,* among others, to which negativity does attach even when no specific context is supplied.

Answer (score 3):

As can be seen from the form of the word, ‘ignorant’, strictly speaking, means ‘having ignorance,  ignoring the facts, not caring’. However, as is often the case, people use the word loosely to suggest lack of knowledge. It is certainly pejorative. It can also imply lack of social grace, particularly in the expression ‘pig ignorant’.

I would say ‘uninformed’ was designed to be emotionally neutral, a mere statement of fact that someone is not in full possession of the facts. However, the manner of delivery of the word can convey contempt. If a governmental policy etc. is described as uninformed, it implies that not enough trouble has been taken to ascertain the facts.

Comment: @BarryBown: No, you have it backwards.  You are carrying the current connotation of _ignore_ onto _ignorant_.   Actually, the primary sense of _ignorare_ in Latin and _ignorer_ in French (i.e. the earlier senses) is simply _to not know_.   The English sense of _to willfully choose to "not know"_ is more recent.

Comment: @ThePopMachine:  Not only is the English sense of *to willfully choose to "not know"* more recent, it is also seldom attested by good writers, who (as you have observed), know what *ignorare* actually means.  By this I mean no offense to the answerer, who of course is more or less right about the words' colloquial usage in some places.

Comment: @thb Modern dictionaries list the 'not know' sense of 'ignore' as archaic, or simply only list the meaning you say is rarely used by good writers. Online Oxford mentions the original sense in the etymology, but does not list it.